# \labelfont from caption package not working

Tags: captions

I am trying to change the font of the label in the caption, but it seems not work. The font is changed in the text of the cation but not in the label 
This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english,oneside]{report}
\sloppy
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,width=150mm,top=20mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace} % This is used in the title page
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colon]{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\captionsetup{font={small}, textfont={sf}, labelfont={bf,sf}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{semtrans}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{texshade}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font choice
\usepackage{tgtermes} %font
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\lstset{%frame=tb,
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true
  tabsize=3
}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    bookmarksopen=true, 
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdftitle={},    % title
    pdfauthor={},     % author
    pdfsubject={},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={},   % creator of the document
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
```

and this what I get back

[image]

I would like to have everything in sf.

Any help?

Thanks

G

Comment: (1) Make a *minimal* example, (2) make an example, you only post preamble, you are much more likely to get help if you post something that can be copied and used without having to add to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler minimal example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes} 
\begin{document}
\bfseries\sffamily
Test
\end{document}
```

this example shows that when `tgtermes` is loaded, there is no bold sans serif. Which is quite odd.

The main problem seems to be that `tgtermes` sets `\bfdefault` to `b`. For sans serif `tgtermes` falls back to CMSS (computer modern sans serif) but that does not use the `b` default, but rather the `bx`.

You can see this from the `.log` file, I get this when I compile the example above

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 12.
```

Might be an idea to find a find a more suitable sans serif font and load that package after `tgtermes`, see http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html

Comment: If I load (even at the beginning) `helvet` or `lmodern`, it's OK. You can try TeX-Gyre Heros, a replacement for Helvetica.

Comment: Hi, it works fine with the minimal example.. the problem is I cannot find why it doesn't work in my preamble. I tried to add packages like float in my minimal example (my test.tex) and none of them seem to bother the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

For unknown reasons, `tgtermes` redefines `\bfdefault` to `b`, which is a very disputable choice.

You can simply revert to the standard `bx` and all will be well, because the font definition files for TeX Gyre Termes *do* contain a font substitution rule from `bx` to `b`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\captionsetup{font={small}, textfont={sf}, labelfont={bf,sf}}

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}

\begin{document}
Test \textbf{test in bold face} test

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{2cm}\rule{3cm}{0pt}}

\caption{Protein expression}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]